# Database design and layout

Tags: mysql, database, layout

I want to revisit a project I made to store user data into a database and improve on the way it is stored. I currently went the hard way about it and stored user data in JSON format within a MySQL database field making it difficult to complete CRUD actions. The reason I did this was to keep all the user's data within the user's field. And was reasonably new to this.

I didn't want to store the data mixed with other user's data and as I thought there may be issues with increased users. for example,

If I had 1000 users with 500 rows of data for each, that's 500 000 rows to sort through when reading the data and displaying it on a web page. And is there a risk of mixing the data up or performance issues?

I basically just want a user database that stores the user's id, name, and credentials. Then another database that will store data from a user's activity(run). So at least 5 fields for each event: Time, location, date, duration, etc. And this will be saved for different events(runs) which could end up in the 100's over a period of time.

My question is, Should I design the table as above. Or would it be better to have a table for each user? Or are there other options that I have not explored?

Comment: A table for users, a table for events, and a table recording which user participated in which event

Answer (score 0):

Given the information shared, I believe below mentioned design may be suitable.

1. Create a Table called User_Details with columns as id (auto increment),user id, name and credentials.
2. Now create a User_Activity Table with these columns id, user_id, event name, data(json field).

Explanation:
The User Activity table will store the event data for you related to each user through user_id field to user_details table. The data which is a json field will help you to store all the fields for the event. As you  are using json field in DB it will allow you to dump any number of fields for the event which may/may not be structured. You can then map this in your middle layer as required.

Also, in case you have finite number of events then you can also create a table called user_event_types and have column id, event name and then in user_activity table you can refer the id instead of event name.